# Separating while loop output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I currently have this small script that outputs a value after each iteration of a while loop:

```
var i = 0;
var number = "";

while (i < 10) {
    number += console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

Which creates this output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

However, I am testing some API calls and using the while loop in JavaScript to see if I can send values consistently, so my values are coming from the script below:

```
var i = 0;
var number = "";

while (i < 10) {
    number += (i);
    i++;
}
```

I do not need console.log() because I do not need the output in the terminal. My issue is when looking at the output on the receiving end when using the API, it looks something like this:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
0123456
01234567
012345678
0123456789
```

The API calls are in the while loop as well, I did not include them because I feel this is a JavaScript syntax related issue. So what will happen is that the while loop begins, `number` is iterated, that value is sent to a website using an API call, and the the while loop begins again. Something like the code below:

```
var i = 0;
var number = "";

while (i < 10) {
    number += (i);

    API_Send(number)

    i++;
}
```

What can I do to so that the output of each iteration is its own separate variable similar to the output using console.log(), so first iteration is 0, second iteration is 1, and so on.

I feel this is something that would be necessary when outputting values to be used by a function. So perhaps it is best to create a function that has a while loop outputting integer values?

Comment: `var number = "";` You're concatenating. Initialize `number` to 0 instead, or reassign `number` completely

Comment: Why you don't use for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { do something... } it will simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared `number` as string, don't do that just assign `0` to `number` variable.
Because of string variable javascript is concatenating the numbers.

Change as following:

```js
var i = 0;
var number = 0;

while (i < 10) {
    number += (i);

    console.log(number)

    i++;
}
```